# How to create a simple Rails app with only a controller /view page ,avoiding all the unnecessary files in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app which contains a single controller(with a method) and a single view page .I would like to avoid all the unnecessary files in my app to keep this in a simple way. I need an app with controller,routes and views. So how should I scaffold my Rails 3 app, so that it contains only a minimal information?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a real simple app, probably you the best fit would be [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)

That is not rails, but implement with ruby.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create the files, especially when you only need a small portion of what the scaffold would create.

1) Add a `statics_controller.rb` to the app/controller directory. If you literally only need one page, you can simply use the index action (name your method index).

2) Add an `index.html.erb` (or .haml) to the app/views/statics/ directory.

3) In your `config/routes.rb` add the line `get '/statics' => 'static#index'`. You can append `, as: 'your_preferred_url` if you want to define your own url.

In all of the above, replace "static" with whatever name you think is appropriate. You would also need to add a model and migration if you plan to interact with a backend database.

I personally feel its good to not use scaffolding initially when you are new to rails so that you fully understand what they are doing.  Scaffolding is not really doing anything fancy or magical. Its often just creating empty files in the correct directories (like I outlined above).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rails scaffold to be very specific in which part of MVC you create. For example,

```
$ rails generate controller Comments
```

or

```
$ rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text post:references
```

I would highly recommend reading the entire Rails Getting Started Guide. But there is a specific section on [generating a controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller) with scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

[Since Rails 6.1.](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-1-adds-minimal-option-support) running `rails new --minimal` gives you an application without all the bells and whistles like action mailer, action mailbox, action text, action job, active storage, action cable, ... and the accompanying configuration and stub files. It then has an `ApplicationRecord`, `ApplicationController` and the basics for an HTML view.